# Why size of stack memory is not 8MB exactly on MacOS?

Tags: c++, macos, operating-system, stack, callstack

I wanted to test the stack size limit on MacOS after I observed that the limit is slightly more than 1MB on Windows (which should be the default limit). I saw that on MacOS even when I don't have any stack memory in use the limit is less than 8MB (default limit) by 18648 bytes, which for me seems quite a lot. I know that calling functions should take some stack space, but the only function being called is the main() and it doesn't have any parameters.

```cpp
#include <iostream>
typedef unsigned int u32;
int main() {
    constexpr u32 bytes_1MB = 1024 * 1024;
    constexpr u32 bytes_8MB = 8 * bytes_1MB;
    constexpr u32 stack_size = 7 * bytes_1MB + 1029928;
    constexpr u32 diff = bytes_8MB - stack_size;
    // std::cout << diff << '\n';
    volatile char arr[stack_size];
}
```

Comment: Doesn't `ulimit` have an effect here?

Comment: I'm not sure the "limit" needs to be a hard cap. It's just a guarantee that *at least* that much stack space is available. There's also some stack space used by the program startup process, `libc`, etc. though you normally don't worry too much about this since it's marginal and if you're pushing the limits of your stack you should either move to dynamic allocation, adjusting `ulimit`, or both.

Comment: as far as i can see, all that code could be optimised away